# Why is structure member accessed using pointer is not getting updated?

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I have a lot of structures in the code that I am working on and for some reason the value of a structure member is not getting updated. I am scratching my head for a long time but could not find the cause. I created a similar code here and this last line is not doing anything.

```
star->state.county.street->pondType = TYPE_SQUARE
```

The pondType remains "TYPE_NONE". Can someone please explain what am I doing wrong?..Thanks!

```
int main()
{
  typedef enum
  {
      TYPE_NONE     = 0,
      TYPE_SQUARE   = 1,
      TYPE_ROUND    = 2,
  } PondType_t;

  typedef struct
  {
      PondType_t pondType;
  } Street_t;

  typedef enum
  {
      IDX_1 = 0,
      IDX_2 = 1,
      IDX_3 = 2,
      MAX_ID_COUNT = 3
  } CompanyID_t;

  typedef struct Company_s
  {
      const CompanyID_t id;
      volatile Street_t *street;
  } Company_t;

  Company_t companies[MAX_ID_COUNT] =
      {
          { .id = IDX_1 },
          { .id = IDX_2 },
          { .id = IDX_3 },
      };

  Company_t *star = &companies[IDX_1];
  star->street->pondType = TYPE_SQUARE;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show a [mcve].

Comment: Why are you putting the includes inside the main function?

Comment: @klutt Sorry, that was done by mistake. I have removed it.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I have reduced the code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is the complete code, then your `street` member points to some random area of memory. Make sure that the target that the pointer points to actually exists. Something like:

```
Street_t street = { 0, TYPE_NONE };
//...
star->state.county.street = &street;
//...
star->state.county.street->pondType = TYPE_SQUARE;
```

Comment: So doesn't that points to a valid memory location when I use this line of code ```Company_t *star = &companies[IDX_1]; ``` ?

Comment: The initializer `{ .id = IDX_1 }` only initializes the `id` member. It leaves the `street` member unbinitialized.